# Return count of connected clients in SignalR. Not firing client function

Tags: signalr

I am trying to return the count of all connections to a web client with SignalR. I increment and persist the client count by firing logic on the hub `OnConnected()` method.

```
public class PopHub : Hub
{
    public static List<string> Users = new List<string>(); 

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var clientId = GetClientId();

        if (Users.IndexOf(clientId) == -1)
        {
            Users.Add(clientId);
        }

        Send(Users.Count);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public void Send(int count)
    {
        Clients.All.updateUsersOnlineCount(count);   
    }
```

stepping through my code with an external console client (to trigger `OnConnected()`) shows that I am traversing through `Send(int count)` with a count of 1.

On my web client, I configure my JS as such

```
$(function() {
    var hub = $.connection.popHub;

    hub.client.updateUsersOnlineCount = function(count) {
        console.log(count);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        console.log('connected');
    });
}());
```

And lastly my snippet from the generated js

```
proxies.popHub = this.createHubProxy('popHub'); 
    proxies.popHub.client = { };
    proxies.popHub.server = {
        popClient: function (message) {
            return proxies.popHub.invoke.apply(proxies.popHub, $.merge(["PopClient"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
         },

        query: function () {
            return proxies.popHub.invoke.apply(proxies.popHub, $.merge(["Query"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
         },

        send: function (count) {
            return proxies.popHub.invoke.apply(proxies.popHub, $.merge(["Send"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
         }
    };
```

**Note that `Popclient` and `Query` are unrelated server side events, of which do work giving me somewhat of a sanity check. Any idea why my clients `updateUsersOnlineCount` function is not logging the count of connections as I expect?

Comment: This probably isn't what is causing `updateUsersOnlineCount` not to log, but you shouldn't modifying a static List<T> inside of OnConnected. The collections found in the System.Collections.Generic namespace are not thread-safe. Instead use a collection from the  System.Collections.Concurrent namespace such as [ConcurrentBag<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it in the OnConnected, please give this a try, it might be that the Base.OnConnected has not been executed yet, so it's not ready to broadcast to clients.

```
//Client
$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        console.log('connected');
        hub.server.ClientCount();
    });

 //Hub
 public static List<string> Users = new List<string>(); 

 public override Task OnConnected()
 {
    var clientId = GetClientId();

    if (Users.IndexOf(clientId) == -1)
    {
        Users.Add(clientId);
    }

    //Send(Users.Count); //not calling this since it's not working

    return base.OnConnected();
 }
 public void ClientCount()
    {
        Clients.All.updateUsersOnlineCount(Users.Count);   
    }
```

Comment: Great I'll give this a try when I get back to my source on Mon. Thank you